# Change the behavior into select tag ( add your own search rules ) with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, select

If i have one text field and after that select box:

```
<input type="text" name="search_into" value="search into select box" />
<select name="" id="list">
<option value="374" >147511 - MARSEILLE 09</option>
<option value="39" >070502 - MARVEJOLS</option>
<option value="127" >030000 - POTIGNY</option>
<option value="201" >141200 - SELESTAT</option>
</select>
```

I want if type "mars" into text filed - automatically selecting the first option.

> "147511 - MARSEILLE 09"

The action must be something like searching and selecting as a background process in one separate text field

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you mean that you want something like [jQuery UI's autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: you can't do that to native elements, RobH comment is close to what you want.

Comment: Where will you type this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, You are right, all that I need is jQuery UI's autocomplete widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xpH5b/1/)

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    $('option:contains("'+$(this).val().toString().toUpperCase()+'")').siblings().attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('option:contains("'+$(this).val().toString().toUpperCase()+'")').removeAttr('disabled').prop('selected','true');
});
```

Comment: yes but without input field, just make search into select box

Comment: Oh, then you are looking for jquery autoComplete like RobH wrote in the comments

Comment: Anton - It's worked perfect for me. So I must use jQuery UI's autocomplete widget?

Comment: yeah jQuery and jQuery UI is all thats needed